# rounded button for newsletter not working in MS mail

Tags: html, css, html-email, newsletter

I need to  make a rounded button for a newsletter, the HTML code is insert in a web base tool used for newsletter

most of the contents are ok but a yellow button with rounded corner on windows 10 mail client lose the rounding and the padding

I try to use different tags like button or change to display block and use the prefixed css style without any success

If is not possible i we will use some images

```
<p><a href="https://mylink.com" target="_blank"><span style="display:inline-block; background-color:#ffce00; padding: 10px 45px; border-radius:20px; color: #000; font-weight: bold;">Click</span></a></p>
```

Comment: Unfortunately `border-radius` isn't supported in most MS email clients, and `padding` has limited support, too - https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this below (I've tested successfully this type of code in MS outlook), the trick is the VML attribute `arcsize`

```html
<div><!--[if mso]>
  <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:200px;" arcsize="50%" stroke="f" fillcolor="#ff0000">
    <w:anchorlock/>
    <center>
  <![endif]-->
      <a href="http://"
style="background-color:#ff0000;border-radius:20px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;line-height:40px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:200px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">Click</a>
  <!--[if mso]>
    </center>
  </v:roundrect>
<![endif]--></div>
```

[Source and Generator](https://buttons.cm/)

Comment: Agree, this is the best approach. `border-radius` isn't supported in Win 10 Mail, so VML is best bet. Specifically the `arcsize` attribute.

Comment: On windows 10 default email client i still see ( as it was before ) the text with a background color, no rounded button. Maybe it use a different rendering engine.

Answer (score 0):

Getting CSS to appear correctly in mail clients is a bit of a pain. When I was doing this type of work we used [Campaign Monitor](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css) compatibility chart before we made formatting decisions.

Another good tool is [Litmus](https://litmus.com/) to check formatting between clients.

Wish I had a better answer for you, hope this helps.